# How to install Command Line Tools on OSX 10.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos, command-line-tool

I found this command: `xcode-select --install`. But if I run it, I get:

```
Usage: xcode-select -print-path
   or: xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path>
   or: xcode-select -version
Arguments:
   -print-path                     Prints the path of the current Xcode folder
   -switch <xcode_folder_path>     Sets the path for the current Xcode folder
   -version                        Prints xcode-select version information
```

Not the installation process.
XCode is 5.1.1.

If I open preferences in XCode, everything seems to be installed.

I've tried to download the "Command Line Tools" from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#, the package for Mountain Lion from April, March and October, but when I ran each of them, I got this error message:
[image]
So at the moment, I don't know what or how to install it.

The problem is, that when I run `bundle update` in my Rails app, I get the error message

```
You have to install development tools first.
```

How to proceed now?

**EDIT:** I managed to install the Command Line Tools from the package, but when I run then the gem installation, the error is still the same:

```
You have to install development tools first.
```

I tested if command line tools are installed like this:

```
xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcode-select -version
xcode-select version 2003.

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

But this should mean it's installed, right? But when I try to install a gem, I get still the line about missing **You have to install development tools first.**

**EDIT2: When I run the brew doctor`, I get this (I guess there might be a connection):

```
Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking.
Set variables:
    DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick++-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Magick-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/MagickCore-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/MagickWand-config
    /opt/ImageMagick/bin/Wand-config

Warning: Your XQuartz (2.7.4) is outdated
Please install XQuartz 2.7.6:
  https://xquartz.macosforge.org

Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please run `xcode-select --install` to install the CLT.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q8.1.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q8.1.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-6.Q8.la
    /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q8.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick-6.Q8.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore-6.Q8.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickCore.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickWand-6.Q8.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/MagickWand.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/Wand-6.Q8.pc
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/Wand.pc

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:

    libpng
```

Comment: I am running 10.9.3 and xcode 5.1.1, and my `xcode-select -v` shows version 2333. Guess you need to reinstall xcode.

Comment: 10.9 Maverick, you try install  "Command Line Tools" from the package for Mountain Lion. This different, try install  "Command Line Tools" for Maverick

Answer (score 1):

If you have the development tools installed, and correct version selected, but you still get the error, you can try following steps which fixed it for me:

1. Download OS X installation from the App Store (for me it was in `/Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app`).
2. Open the *InstallESD.dmg* image: `open /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg`.
3. Look for *Essentials.pkg* in *Packages* folder.
4. Run the *Essentials* installation.

**WARNING: Please beware that reinstalling parts of you OS might break it and I don't take responsibility for it, so backup before you hack around :-) !!!**

Alternatively you can buy a software (e.g. [AnyToIso](http://www.crystalidea.com/anytoiso) or [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/)) and extract just the needed file.

**UPDATE:** The extracted file can be found on [Clinic's GitHub repo](https://github.com/cinic/install-name-tool).